# Returning Json Data To PHP Variables

Tags: php, json

I know there are a lot of similar question as this one on here but the problem I keep running into is that the method in which those other json file arrays are setup is not the same as mine.

What I am trying to do should just be a simple process but as I am not as versed in json arrays and I am other things, the solution is eluding me completely.

I just want to take the data display in a local json file and create PHP variables for each item returned.

The json file is simple and looks something like this...

```
[
    {
        "titleOne": "Foo",
        "textOne": "Bar",
        "titleTwo": "Foo",
        "textTwo": "Bar"
    }
]
```

It will always consist of just these 4 items.   Then I use the following PHP to read and decode the file...

```
$data = file_get_contents ('./data.json');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            echo $key . '====>' . $val . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

but this simply outputs the data.  I am trying to get each one of these 4 items to become variables.  Example...

```
$titleOne
$textOne
$titleTwo
$textTwo
```

...so that the variables can be used in a form.

I have found many similar questions as this but the json data is always setup differently resulting in errors as results.

Comment: Just access the array entries in your form, e.g. `$json[0]['titleOne']`

Comment: I am not that educated with json arrays.  Could you explain as to how I can do that please?

Comment: Just use, e.g. `$json[0]['titleOne']`

Comment: I've updated my comment. For further research, the term you are wanting is `associative array`, rather than explicitly json arrays.

Comment: Or consider `$json = json_decode($data, true)[0];` and then just `$json['titleOne']`, `$json['textOne']`, etc.

Comment: Now how do I mark this as the best answer if it's just a comment?  lol... thank you very much... that was exactly what I needed.  I was trying that but was missing the [0] part this whole time.

Comment: have you tried doing a print_r on the returned data? that usually works for me so that i can see the structure of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply define if it's always only 4:

```
$titleOne = $json[0]['titleOne'];
$textOne = $json[0]['textOne'];
$titleTwo = $json[0]['titleTwo'];
$textTwo = $json[0]['textTwo'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [list](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to extract elements into variables. Keep in mind, that it only works with numerical arrays.

```
$json = '[
    {
        "titleOne": "Foo",
        "textOne": "Bar",
        "titleTwo": "Foo",
        "textTwo": "Bar"
    }
]';

$json = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($json as $object) {
    list($titleOne, $textOne, $titleTwo, $textTwo) = array_values($object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>With php you can't use a variable to name another variable.</strike> You could however use an associative array to do this.

The `true` in `json_decode($data, true);` already returns the data in the form of an associative array. In order to access the value of titleOne, you would just do `$json['titleOne']`. This would give you `Foo`.

Comment: Are you about `$$varname`? Or `${'title'}`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hmm, sorry. I was thinking of a completely different language. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With php you CAN use a variable to name another variable.
Just use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) :

```
$a = 'var';
$$a = 'hello world';
echo $var;
// output : hello word
```

In your case :

You don't have to wrap your json data in array and make 2 loops :

```
{
    "titleOne": "Foo",
    "textOne": "Bar",
    "titleTwo": "Foo",
    "textTwo": "Bar"
}
```

You can create your dynamic variables this way :

```
$data = file_get_contents ('./data.json');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($json as $key => $val) {
    $$key = $val;
}
echo $titleOne;
// output : Foo
```